# Which is better in use between int and Integer to determine the values?

Tags: java, integer, int

I would like to know when I am checking for integers input, should I use int or Integer for checking?

Below is some mock-up codes:

This one uses int:

```
public State editState (int stateID, String stateCode) {
    if (stateID == 0) {
        throw new Exception("State id not set.");
    }
    ...
    State s = new State();
    ...

    return s;
}
```

This one uses Integer:

```
public State editState (Integer stateID, String stateCode) {
    if (stateID == null) {
        throw new Exception("State id not set.");
    }
    ...
    State s = new State();
    ...

    return s;
}
```

Which approach is better in use?

Comment: Use enum! `enum State`

Comment: `int` is a primitive. `Integer` is a wrapper on `int`. AutoBoxing/ Unboxing is done by the compiler. So, unless you have explicit need to store the primitive `int` as an `Integer` *object*, I'd almost always go with `int`.

Comment: @icza in which row do i use enum?

Comment: @TheLostMind i've just think of using casting like for first approach, (Integer)stateID == null, does this approach slightly better?

Comment: @user3743562 icza does not say you use enum. He urges you to use enum :) And I tend to second his opinion.

Comment: @Fildor oops, its the first time i heard of enum, working on research for enum documentation :) thanks anyway~

Comment: There you go: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: @user3743562 - No, don't use casting.. Like others mention, use `enums`.

Comment: @TheLostMind i see.. well just got documentation from the leader, int will be used :)

Answer (score 2):

when you will invoke editState(..,..) and stateId is not set then  two cases arise-

1)editState(0,"some code");

2)editState(null,"some code");

It depends upon the criteria you set for the unacceptance of stateID.

If you set criteria for unacceptance as null then you will have to use 'Integer'
 and if 0 then you can use both 'Integer' and 'int' ...

so it depends upon the criteria you set at the invoking side..

And i think Integer (wrapper class ) is better due to excellent auto boxing ,unboxing features
as well as various methods provided to you for manipulations if required...

Answer (score 1):

There is no much difference performance wise or functionality wise. Both would be almost equal. It depends more on how the input is in the method invoking the editState(...) method. If the invoking method has primitive type int or wrapper Integer, corresponding editState(...) is better to use.
Also, if the invoking method has the possibility of different numeric types (byte, short etc.) that fits into int, then first one is preferred. Similarly if it has object that can be autoboxed to Integer, then second one is preferred.

Comment: Well, I'd say we have to take a step backwards. It is a question of design. Do we want to represent "No State" by a specific StateId ( for example "0") or do we want to represent "No State" by the null reference. Personally, I'd prefer the specific Id - Design which I would work into a specific enum - constant , for example State.UNKNOWN or State.NONE. If you have a user dictate the Interface you will not be happy for long.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in Java an `int` is a primitive while an `Integer` is an `Object`. Meaning, if you made a new `Integer`:

```
Integer i = new Integer(6);
```

You could call some method on i:

```
String s = i.toString(); //sets s the string representation of i
```

Whereas with an `int`:

```
int i = 6;
```

You cannot call any methods on it, because it is simply a primitive. So:

```
String s = i.toString(); //will not work!!!
```

would produce an error, because int is not an object.

I think if you have not any requirement to use such operation then go with `int` instead of `Integer` and you can also avoid a unnecessary Java object creation.

Comment: i see... well just got documentation from the leader, int will be used :) thanks anyway ;)